# how to get a list of files from a given path of directory in string in flutter web?

Tags: flutter, flutter-web

I have a string of path like this:

"C:\xxxx\xxx\xxxx"

how can I get the list of files from this path?

Eventually, I want to load all the files.

Answer (score 0):

If your result is a website, you cannot. No technology can do that, it's a limitation of websites in general, they can only read what you specifically select in your browser. It would be a security nightmare if any website could just go browsing your local disk.

If you need to do that, the user would have to select/upload multiple files themselves or if you really, really need that, you may want to consider a native app, in this case probably [flutter-desktop](/questions/tagged/flutter-desktop).

Comment: who about inside the project folder? i mean the subfolders in the project.

Comment: Why would you want this? Maybe you should ask the question you want to ask ("How do I do...") instead of probing all technical possibilities. What do you *want* to do, in plain English?

Comment: The question is legit. Say you have a folder with images on server side and want to make a gallery. You need to list files in a folder that is part of the project.

Comment: @log0 Well, if you know how to do that using [flutter-web], feel free to contribute an answer. To display something you have server-side, you don't open a path or read folders, you connect to a backend. That's why I asked what the OP wanted to *do* in plain English.

Comment: yeah sure I was about to post an answer. Just understood how to list file assets.

Answer (score 0):

As said by @nvoigt a website cannot access the user's computer without requesting the user.

Assuming the directory is part of the project's assets i.e. the folder is deployed with your website, you can read the list of files from the AssetManifest.json.

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';

final manifestContent = await rootBundle.loadString('AssetManifest.json');
final Map<String, dynamic> manifestMap = json.decode(manifestContent);
List filePaths = manifestMap.keys
    .where((String key) => key.contains('mydir/')).toList()
```